# Facebook Authentication / Connect

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-authentication

I'm developing a student web portal for a college and I want to implement some of Facebook's social networking features in it. The major thing I want to do is allow students to login with their Facebook credentials. We receive a ton of help desk tickets about students needing to reset their student passwords because they've forgotten it, so I'm hoping this will cure that problem somewhat.

However the student portal is only accessible to students who currently have an application and account on file with the college. Is there a way to only allow Facebook Authentication to work for users that currently have a user account with the college?

Answer (score 1):

You would most likely need to add your own system where you verify an account either with a flag such as "verified" and someone would need to manually verify them in a back-end system. Then when a user logs in, you check this flag against the facebook id. So when the user first connects, you add the facebook id to a DB and set verified to false. Perhaps at registration asking for the college email address to send a verification code to. You could then connect the facebook id to an existing college email address in your database. Alternatively make this check automatic, so if they enter a valid email, it updates to verified (though people could obviously make up a false college email if the format is consistent). So you link their facebook account to an existing student portal account (alternatively use something similar like a student-id )

Facebook doesn't offer this kind of system out of the box as far as I know, so you would have to develop your own system to verify the account against some info that you know.